# Recursively assign new keys to a multidimensional array to indicate the elements' depth and count

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, key

I need to reassign all of the keys in an array.  The key in each level need to contain a static string plus an incremented number.  If an element is an array, the new keys of that child array should should contain the parent's key + a separating underscore and an incremented counter on that level.

Sample arrays:

```
$a = [
    'pos1' => 'somedata',
    'pos2' => ['data2', 'data3'],
    'pos3' => '';
];
```

And

```
$b = [
    [
        'pos1' => ['data1', 'data2', ['nest1', 'nest2']],
        'pos2' => ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
    ],
    ['data1', 'data2'],
    'data4',
];
```

Desired results:

```
$a = [
    'pos1' => 'somedata',
    'pos2' => [
        'pos2_1' => 'data2',
        'pos2_2' => 'data3'
    ],
    'pos3' => '';
];
```

and

```
$b = [
    'pos1' => [
        'pos1_1' => [
            'pos1_1_1' => 'data1', 
            'pos1_1_2' => 'data2', 
            'pos1_1_3' => [
                'pos1_1_3_1' => 'nest1', 
                'pos1_1_3_2' => 'nest2',
            ],
        ],
        'pos1_2' => [
            'pos1_2_1' => 'data1',
            'pos1_2_2' => 'data2',
            'pos1_2_3' => 'data3',
        ],
    ],
    'pos2' => [
        'pos2_1' => 'data1',
        'pos2_2' => 'data2'
    ],
    'pos3' => 'data4',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to assign new level-related keys to all elements in the array.

Pass the extended parent key into the  function on each recursive call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kBCDs))

```
function leveledKeys($array, $key = 'pos'): array
{
    $result = [];
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        $result[$key . "_$i"] = is_array($v)
            ? leveledKeys($v, $key . "_$i")
            : $v;
        ++$i;
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(leveledKeys($a));
echo "\n";
var_export(leveledKeys($b));
```